# Atomic repo to just update Ossec and not the rest is that possible for Centos 6.4?

Tags: centos, repository

I followed this link http://www.ossec.net/?page_id=19 and enable both epel and atomic repo to install ossec. My problem is I just want a local installation of ossec so I ran this yum install osssec-hids. Is this correct? Secondly now each time I do yum update I get a whole list of updates from atomic too which I am not dare to update but I just want it to update ossec only is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Edit the yum repo, and add a `include=ossec-hids*` to it, so it only includes those packages.

Comment: @Where is the yum repo file ? I am not too sure is it in /etc/

Comment: Ok I know where it is but I did something like this 
enabled = 1
priority =99
protect = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY.art.txt
gpgcheck = 1
include = ossec-hids*
 then I try to this got error yum install ossec-hids ossec-hids-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.repos.d/ossec-hids*